# Asp.net Identity - log each login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I want to log each login to my admin pages. I easily do this on my Login() method, but how can I track each successful login done because the isPersistent cookie is set? In other words, how can I track when a user is auto logged in because of the cookie?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. This would mean that you log each and every request including requests for static resources.

Comment: The auto log on you refer to is effectively an authenticated request. The request could be twenty seconds, two minutes or two days after the initial login that created the authentication cookie - obviously subject to the validity period of your authentication cookie. Which requests do you want to log? Every time a user is authenticated, or only after a period of inactivity?

Comment: What I want to do is to log the last time a user was active. I see your point about period of inactivity. To be hones I am not quite sure what the ideal here would be. The main point is that I would like to be able to track the last time a user was active, and of course not for each request for a page.

For example if a user login in the morning, then does nothing, and comes back 2 hours later and does some changes, I would like to update the last active time.

Comment: I ended up doing this in Session_Start so I could log each new session if Identity User was set

Answer (score 0):

Each page accessed is typically logged in the IIS http server logs and includes by default the URL requested and the username. Would this fulfill your logging requirements without anymadditional work?

Comment: I did the logging in the Session_Start method where I could do what I wanted, thanks.